# Jmeter script is not logging right every time

Tags: jmeter

I have a script that is logging in and navigating to a different page.  Sometimes this works but some time it doesn't. I am unable to pin point the reasons.  I have tokens taken care of. When it does not run properly it is redirecting to the login page. I can see the tokens are properly used until this point but I cannot figure it out why it is throwing the page back at login.

Can someone help me resolving this please?

Comment: I think you have to look into your server it might be bug in your server.

Comment: please post the kind of code you are using and pointing issues